# K-Medoids / K-Means Algorithm. Data point with the equal distances between two or more cluster representatives

Tags: algorithm, distance, data-mining, k-means

I have been researching and studying about partition-based clustering algorithms like K-means and K-Medoids. I have learned that K-medoids is more robust to outliers compared to K-means. However I am curious on what will happen if during the assigning of data points, two or more cluster representatives have the same distance on a data point. Which cluster will you assign the data point? Will the assignment of the data point to a cluster greatly affect the clustering results?

Answer (score 2):

To prevent bad things from happening (infinite loops etc.) always prefer the cluster the point already is assigned to when tied.

Comment: How can you say that "to prevent bat things from happening (infinite loops etc.)"? Can you please give me an example.

Comment: Points switching back and forth between the same two clusters forever.